# E117: Unknown function: ale#Lint

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I try upgrading my `.vimrc` file. When I open up a Rails application I'm working on I get the following error.

```
rails_app/config/environments/development.rb                                                                    2,3            Top
Error detected while processing CursorHold Auto commands for "*":
E117: Unknown function: ale#Lint
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The error is thrown from [Ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) I guess from the following line.

```
" ALE linting events
augroup ale
  autocmd!

  if g:has_async
    set updatetime=1000
    let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 0
    autocmd CursorHold * call ale#Lint()
    autocmd CursorHoldI * call ale#Lint()
    autocmd InsertEnter * call ale#Lint()
    autocmd InsertLeave * call ale#Lint()
  else
    echoerr "The thoughtbot dotfiles require NeoVim or Vim 8"
  endif
augroup END
```

On the `vimrc.bundles` I have the following line.

```
if g:has_async
  Plug 'w0rp/ale'
endif
```

Is there a reason why ale is not being installed properly?

Comment: Seeing that you also have [different plugin problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072061/e492-not-an-editor-command-nerdtree), you really need to check your `'runtimepath'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ale#Lint needs be replaced with ale#Queue(0)

See relevant pull request:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/pull/615/files

Comment: this fix causes the error to changes from `ale#Lint ` to `ale#Queue(0)`. This patch didn't work for me